# Stop Thunderbird Attaching Images When Sending Email

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have a HTML email that I am sending and it contains images that are hosted on my website and not inside the email.

For example:

```
<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/a.jpg"/>
```

When I paste my HTML into Thunderbird (using Insert->HTML) and send it Thunderbird automatically turns those images into attachments on the email. How do you stop Thunderbird attaching images to an email?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Insert->HTML, use Insert->Image. Type/paste the URL into the Image Location box. Then uncheck "Attach this image to the message" (alt-S).

Answer (score 0):

This should possibly be a comment, but it's too long.

You could try to insert it as the Base64 data string.

"Convert" your graphic to the string using this website http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

And in your HTML, use

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,PutTheBase64DataStringHere" />
```